# tcl exec result redirected to stdout need to be stored too

Tags: exec, tcl, stdout

Lake a look at this two lines

**case 1**

```
set cvsUpdStr [exec cvs -qn upd]
```

**case 2**

```
set cvsUpdStr [exec cvs -qn upd >&@stdout]
```

For the first case `cvsUpdStr` is the output of the command, but there is nothing printed out during command execution. For the second case the `cvs upd` command output is printed on the screen, but `cvsUpdStr` is empty. How to combine them so that it will print out the result of `cvs upd` and also will store the same output in `cvsUpdStr` variable?

Comment: If you are especially interested in CVS things, you might have a look at tkcvs, as it already wraps most CVS commands with Tcl. http://tksvn.tigris.org/source/browse/tksvn/trunk/tkcvs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possibilities. Either run it as a pipeline (created with `open |...`) and handle the messages as they come in by storing them and printing them, or use the Unix `tee` utility. The second alternative is definitely simpler!

```
# I like to spell out “update” in full
set cvsUpdStr [exec cvs -qn update | tee /dev/tty]
```

The `tee` program sends its standard input to its normal standard output plus the named file; we use `/dev/tty` to send it to the current terminal.

Note however that you may get long delays in the output of `cvs` due to it buffering its output. This is just the default behavior of the C library's I/O handling when sending output to a non-terminal, and can be a problem if you need the output instantly. Fixing this gets quite involved (you end up using Expect) so if you're happy with the output being bursty, just leave it alone…

---

On Windows, you need to do it the other way.

```
set pipe [open |[list cvs -qn update] "r"]
while {[gets $pipe line] >= 0} {
    append cvsUpdStr "$line\n"   ;# Note the \n at the end!
    puts $line
}
close $pipe                      ;# Any errors turn up here!
```

The construct with `|[list ...]` is rather unusual in Tcl terms, but it is the correct one to use in this situation. (If the first character of the “filename” to `open` is a `|`, the *rest* of the argument is treated as a list of arguments to use for building a pipeline.)

Comment: I am on widows, about tee I knew, but it does not help here :(

Comment: What is the solution with `open | ...`?

Comment: Thanks you very much, but could you explain in details this part: `set pipe [open |[list cvs -qn update] "r"]` ?

Comment: @Narek What's to explain? It opens `cvs` as a subprocess in a pipeline; the output of `cvs` is what you read from the `$pipe` channel. The `exec` command does the same sort of thing internally, but doesn't return until the subprocess finishes.